# Inject byte[] exported from MethodInfo.GetMethodBody()

Tags: c#, cil, reflection.emit, inject

I was wondering, if it's possible to inject byte[] code that was previously exported from an method via GetMethodBody() back, meaning, that it can be runnable code again. If someone could write pretty simple example or explanation I'd appreciate.

Regards,

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating method dynamically, and executing it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7671220/creating-method-dynamically-and-executing-it)

Comment: I do know how to dynamically create new method.

What I want to do is extracted and storted method in byte[] turn in runnable code and execute it.

Comment: Have you read the answers to that question?

Comment: Sorry, I thought that they were talking about something else when I read the title of the question. Thanks again svick !

Answer (score 0):

```
byte[] il = ...;
MethodBuilder mb = ...;
mb.CreateMethodBody(il, il.Length);
```

Comment: nvm, indeed is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7671220/creating-method-dynamically-and-executing-it

Answer (score -1):

Indeed you can.
You can execute IL code using [DynamicMethod.GetILGenerator()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xcbx21sk.aspx). There is an example in the link.

Comment: But that doesn't let you execute code that you have as `byte[]`.